# Sorting and removing duplicate from a file with character and numeric values

Tags: shell, file, sorting, unix, duplicates

I have this file:

```
1kg_1_100990624 rs768670248
rs3176861 rs1011842035
imm_12_2853458 rs951444582
1kg_14_80512920 rs902703491
8_41638322 rs56288115
```

The values of the 1° columns are different while the values of the 2° columns are always in the same format. It's very long and I want to sort it and then remove all duplicates. I use `sort -k1 file.txt` and then `sort -u file.txt` but it not removes duplicates.

for "duplicate" I mean:

```
1kg_14_80512920 rs902703491
1kg_14_80512920 rs950301252
```

in this case I take only the first line (1kg_14_80512920 rs902703491) and removing all other lines (entire lines, os both 1° and 2° columns).

How can I solve ?

Comment: define "duplicates" please. remove col1 duplicates or whole line? We cannot read that from your description or your example either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove the duplicates give this a try:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file
```

If you want the result to be sorted, you can pass the result to sort:

```
awk .... file | sort
```

or first sort then remove dups:

```
sort file | awk '!a[$1]++'
```

Comment: What is the difference between '!a[$1]++' and '!a[$0]++' in this case ?

Comment: @Will $1 will compare and do unique on $1, while $0, will do it on whole line.